# scaffolding and grid systems in twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently using the bootstrap scaffolding/grid system as follows:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div id="insta-shop-filter" class="span2 visible-desktop">

    </div>
    <div  id="insta-shop-grid" class="span10">

    </div>
<div>
```

As you can see I added the visible-desktop to `insta-shop-filter` so that this will disappear on non-desktop. However what I wanted to do is that when this disappears I wanted `insta-shop-grid` to have a `span12`, so it takes the full width. Is there a way to do this without having to use javascript/jQuery and listening for window events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS3 media queries to toggle your styling on different devices. In this instance, you might consider writing a media query based on a 640px or 480px device width that does something like the following:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width:640px){
  #insta-shop-filter{
     display:none;
  }
  #insta-shop-grid{
     width:640px!important;
  }
}
```

One small note here, using !important is discouraged.

Comment: how does this change the class from span10 to span12? Because that's what I wanted

Comment: it won't but it will override the width attribute from the span10, effectively giving you a full width instead of 10/12 of the width

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap 2 (which it appears you are using) I don't think there is an easy way to do this without overriding the style with a custom CSS media query (like @Conqueror suggested) or adding/removing classes in javascript.

However I just want to point out that this is baked into Bootstrap3 by using `col-SIZE-SPAN` as [documented here](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#migration-new). In your case it would be.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div id="insta-shop-filter" class="col-md-2 hidden-sm">

    </div>
    <div  id="insta-shop-grid" class="col-md-10 col-sm-12">

    </div>
<div>
```